# Calculating max difference between values and recording the time both values took place in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition

I am trying to find the largest difference in temperature in any 24 hour period and return the amount of time it took for said difference to take place. The code below successfully finds the differences in max and min temperature for any given 24-hour window, however, I need to also return the date/time information for each of the max and min temperatures in order to calculate the amount of time between them.

How would I change this query to keep track of which date/time is associated with the MAX(o.temp) over, MIN(o.temp) over lines?

```
SELECT
o.long_date as long_date
,MAX(o.temp) over (order by o.unix range between 86400 preceding and current row) as max_temp
,MIN(o.temp) over (order by o.unix range between 86400 preceding and current row) as min_temp
FROM
(
SELECT 
unix_time AS unix
,date as long_date
,temp AS temp
FROM oshkosh 
WHERE temp != -9999) as o
```

outputs

```
o.unix      long_date           max_temp    min_temp
946687980   2000-01-01 00:53:00 35.1    35.1
946691580   2000-01-01 01:53:00 35.1    35.1
946695180   2000-01-01 02:53:00 35.1    35.1
946698780   2000-01-01 03:53:00 34.0    34.0
946702380   2000-01-01 04:53:00 32.0    32.0
946705980   2000-01-01 05:53:00 30.9    30.9
946709580   2000-01-01 06:53:00 28.0    28.0
946713180   2000-01-01 07:53:00 28.0    28.0
946716780   2000-01-01 08:53:00 28.0    28.0
946720380   2000-01-01 09:53:00 33.1    33.1
946723980   2000-01-01 10:53:00 34.0    34.0
946727580   2000-01-01 11:53:00 36.0    36.0
946731180   2000-01-01 12:53:00 35.1    35.1
946734780   2000-01-01 13:53:00 34.0    34.0
946738380   2000-01-01 14:53:00 33.1    33.1
```